# Installinng psycopg2 on Mac, pg_config executable not found

Tags: macos, psycopg2

```
Error: pg_config executable not found.
    
    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:
    
        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...
    
    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.
    
    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.
    
    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).
    
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command outpu
```

Comment: If you are doing this on a Mac the tag should be ```macos``` not ```ios```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message gives you the solution:

```
If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI

psycopg2-binary' package instead.
```

If you do:

`pip install psycopg2`

you need to have the Postgres development libraries installed on your machine.

**UPDATE**

So do as the error message suggests:

`pip install psycopg2-binary`

Then you do not need the development libraries.

Comment: ¡Hola! Yo ya descargue Postgresql en local, pero tampoco funciona. 
Cuando instalo me sale este error:

 "Problema al ejecutar el paso post instalación. La instalación no pudo finalizar correctamente La inicialización del clúster de la base de datos falló."

Comment: Are you pip installing psycopg2? 
Your other comment needs to be a separate question.

Comment: I installed Postgresql and now in the visualr studio code terminal I want to run the command pip install psycopg2, but I have errors.

And now I remember that when I installed Postgresql I got that error from the clusters, I don't know if it has anything to do with it.

Comment: No it is not related. See UPDATE to my answer. That will install psycopg2. Though it will not do  anything about your local install of Postgres.  Create a new question for that issue.

Comment: I did what you told me and it works, but then I run python manage.py makemigrations and you get another error

Comment: That is due to your other issue. You need a working Postgres instance to run against. StackOverflow questions need to be focused to one issue at a time. Start another question for your install problem.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver tried psycopg2-binary still gives me same error pg_config executable not found.

Comment: @utopictown, you need to create a question with details of what you did, the Macos version and the complete error message.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver its mac m1 monterey. did exactly what the OP do and have the exact error message. thats why im here. if i start new question itd be marked as duplicate

Comment: The answer worked for @MocaWeb so your situation must be different. Start a new question with the information I asked for.